# GDM hangs a long time

Tags: gnome

When I start gdm it shows the login dialog box swiftly. But after entering my credentials it takes a long time before the gnome session is shown. If it is shown...
In the logs of GDM I see:

> gdm[26918]: DEBUG: Sending LOGIN ==  for slave 26918
>
> gdm[26914]: DEBUG: Handling message: 'LOGIN 26918 user'
>
> gdm[26918]: DEBUG: Timeout occurred for sending message LOGIN 26918 user

It seems that the internal messaging of GDM is not functioning correctly.
When I start gnome-session with startx it works fine and I get my desktop quickly.
Strange though is that if I type `exit` in a gnome-terminal the terminal is not closing. Even though the setting in de preferences is set. And it always used to function the correct way.

My problems probably have something to do with my attempt to migrate to `system` instead of `init.d`...

Thank you very much for any help in fincing the trouble.

MAG,
Milo

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found what the problem was. By adding some extra debug info to gdm.c and slave.c I found out that the SIGUSR2 handler was not working anymore. gdm.c is sending SIGUSR2 as soon as the acknowledgement to a message is send to the pipe but it was never received/handled by the slave. I also found out that login to root functioned and that even completely clearing my homedir did not help. So there must be something crashing the gdm/greeter after based on user account and and not based on the profile in the homedir.
The only difference left was that my own account had a valid fingerprint and fingerprint reading was set in system-auth in /etc/pam.d. After removing fingerprint authentication from pam all is fine again :)